# CertManager can't generate TLS certificate for my domain

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, cert-manager

I am deploying my application on a Scaleway Kapsule Kubernetes cluster and I am trying to generate TLS certificate from Let's Encrypt using Cert-Manager. Here is my resources :

---

Secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
stringData:
  SCW_ACCESS_KEY: XXX
  SCW_SECRET_KEY: XXX
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: scaleway-secret
type: Opaque
```

---

Issuer:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: scaleway
spec:
  acme:
    email: xxx
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # for production use this URL instead
    # server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: scaleway-acme-secret
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        webhook:
          groupName: acme.scaleway.com
          solverName: scaleway
          config:
            accessKeySecretRef:
              key: SCW_ACCESS_KEY
              name: scaleway-secret
            secretKeySecretRef:
              key: SCW_SECRET_KEY
              name: scaleway-secret
```

---

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-lb
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: scaleway
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: mydomain.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.example.com
    secretName: mydomain.example.com-cert
```

But I encounter a strange error that I did not find in the internet and in any of the forums :

```
Error presenting challenge: failed to update DNS zone recrds: scaleway-sdk-go: http error 403 Forbidden: domain not found
```

My domain is pointing to the IP of the loadbalancer as it should and it's working. What could it be ?

Comment: Your role has no right to manipulate the DNS record.

Comment: Should I create a new Scaleway API key with more privilieges to manipulate the DNS record ?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I am using Scaleway Kapsule ( version of Kubernetes 1.2 ),

Comment: Are you sure you are using Kubernetes 1.2 (released in March 2016)? :)

Comment: My bad i forgot to edit it :D, it's Kubernetes 1.22 :
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.5", GitCommit:"aea7bbadd2fc0cd689de94a54e5b7b758869d691", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-09-15T21:10:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.3", GitCommit:"c92036820499fedefec0f847e2054d824aea6cd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-27T18:35:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: If you are using Scaleway Kapsule did you try to ask your dedicated support? At this moment Kubernetes configs looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

`failed to update DNS zone recrds: scaleway-sdk-go: http error 403 Forbidden`

Your role has no right over the registered domain, see the documentation [here](https://developers.scaleway.com/en/products/domain/dns/api/#permissions).

Comment: When I curled informations about my token, i notice this field : "inherits_user_perms": false. So the problem is permissions.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on how to add rights or permissions to an API token or a user.